# How angular page is called from spring boot rest

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to implement forgotPasswordPage.I am sending verification email to user.If user clicks link,then rest function is called.If operation is successfull I need to redirect Angular Password change page.
How will be redirection, how can I call angular page from java spring boot rest. It is possible for jsp but In angular I can not find."redirect" and "forward" does not work in project.Returns string.Do you have any ideas.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your angular code that is doing the request should handle this.

inject the [`Router`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router):

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

...
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

call the router when the rest call succeeds:

```
this.router.navigate(['/change-password']);
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I want to call angular page from backend.It is for in ui call

Comment: Hmm, okay I assumed that the link goes into the ui and from there you make the rest call. You can't call an angular page from the server side code. What you can do is to set a http `Location` header with the target url on the response. That tells the browser to call the given url.